# Combining server side and client side errors in ngMessage

Tags: angularjs, ng-messages

I have an mdDialog which does some server side validation on submit. I'm trying to find a way to combine error messages. The problem is that I need to clear the server side errors before each submit attempt and I don't want to type in the name of each possible error.

So I'm doing it by assigning a prefix to such codes and clearing them manually. This looks very hacky though. Is there a more Angular way to add server-side errors to $error of the fields so they can be used with ngMessages?

**Example JSON error response from server (one property for each failed field):**

```
{"name":"svr_nameduplicated", "anotherfield":"svr_somethingwrong", ...}
```

**Dialog excerpt:**

```
<md-dialog-content>
  <div class="md-dialog-content">
     <md-input-container>
         <label>Name:</label>
         <input type="text" name="name" data-ng-model="product.name" md-maxlength="40" required/>
         <div ng-messages="productForm.name.$error" role="alert">
            <div ng-message="required">Name is required.</div>
            <div ng-message="md-maxlength">Name is too long.</div>
            <div ng-message="svr_nameduplicated">Duplicate name.</div>
         </div>
     </md-input-container>
  </div>
</md-dialog-content>
```

**Controller:**

```
function EditProductDialogController($scope, $mdDialog, product, productIdx) {
    $scope.productIdx = productIdx;
    $scope.product = product;

    $scope.cancel = function() {
        $mdDialog.cancel();
    }

    $scope.save = function() {
        clearServerSideErrors($scope.productForm);
        if ($scope.productForm.$valid) {
            var options = {headers : {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': self.csrf}};
            $http.put(contextPath + '/prod/ang/update/' + product.id, product, options)
                .then(function(response) {
                    $mdDialog.hide({product: $scope.product, productIdx: $scope.productIdx});
                },
                function(errResponse) {
                    addServerSideErrors($scope.productForm, errResponse.data);
                });         
        }
    }
}
```

**Hackish utility functions:**

```
// walk on form fields and set errors whose code starts with svr_ to valid
function clearServerSideErrors(form) {
    for (var prop in form) {
        if (form.hasOwnProperty(prop) && !prop.startsWith('$')) {
            for (var prop2 in form[prop].$error) {
                if (prop2.startsWith('svr_')) {
                    form[prop].$setValidity(prop2, true);
                }
            }
        } 
    }
}

// walk on error object returned from server and add errors to $error of fields
function addServerSideErrors(form, errors) {
    for (var prop in errors) {
        form[prop].$setValidity(errors[prop], false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use async validators.

Comment: I'm integrating this into a 'classic' Spring MVC application (which I cannot change) where there is only mass validation on submit.